# Mount APFS on Ubuntu Error while using apfs-fure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, disk-image, apfs

I have an apfs disk with some information that I need to access on my desktop. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I have looked to this article to find all the steps I need to be able to do this (https://linuxnewbieguide.org/how-to-mount-macos-apfs-disk-volumes-in-linux/). I have taken all the steps up to the part where I have to actually mount the drive by performing a command similar to this

```
sudo apfs-fuse -o allow_other /dev/sdc2 /media/$USERNAME/macos
```

/dev/sdc2 is the drive I am trying to mount and I confirmed this by running sudo fdisk -l. This is what I get when I run it

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 223.58 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: ADATA SU635     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 17DB2AC1-9D2E-462E-8F88-D774546991C1

Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1      40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sdc2  411648 468860927 468449280 223.4G unknown
```

I'm assuming the 223.4G part is what I need. Anyways, the problem is whenever I run the first command mentioned to mount the disk, I get this error.

```
Unable to get volume!
```

I've looked everywhere on how to fix this and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (changed the value of g_vol_id from 0 to 1 in the ApfsFuse.cpp file). After recompilation, copy them again.
https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse/issues/167

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that doesn't require recompilation. You should specify vol param

```
apfs-fuse -o vol=0 /dev/sdb3 ~/disks/data
apfs-fuse -o vol=1 /dev/sdb2 ~/disks/backup
```